# Plot multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of, say:

```
size P = zeros(2,2,100);
```

Let's try to plot the first element of each of these matrices, like this:

```
plot(1:1:100, P(1,1,:))
```

This does not work. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try plot(squeeze(P(1,1,:)).

The squeeze() function removes singleton dimensions (dimensions whose size are 1).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Create arrays manually. Not very elegant but works.

```
% tl = top left, br = bottom right, etc.
for i=1:1:100
    tlplot(i) = P(1, 1, i);
    trplot(i) = P(1, 2, i);
    blplot(i) = P(2, 1, i);
    brplot(i) = P(2, 2, i);
end
```

Then, for instance:

```
plot(1:1:100, tlplot)
```