# how to plot multidim array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d, plot, surf

I got a function of three parameters that I wanted to plot in matlab and I varied the values of the parameters (50 values for each parameter) for creating a multidimensional array 50x50x50. At first I want to plot it with surf, then with contourn3, but I don't know how to do this. I want to see the trend of this function.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806190/plot-multidimensional-array-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you have some sort of function like `value = fun(parmA, parmB, parmC)`, and want to visualize how `value` changes w.r.t. the parameters. Unfortunately there is no way to visualize all of the data at once in a single graphic. You have to choose one of the dimensions to hold constant.

We can visualize 3-D data using a surface plot, `surf()`, or level contours `contour()`. These work when we have something like `value = fun(parmA, parmB)`, or `z = fun(x,y)`. So the best alternative you have is step through one of the dimensions and generate a new surface or contour plot for each value.

Using a short delay, you can actually generate a video. Here is a simple example. You might have to do a little extra work if you want to hold the axes constant throughout.

```
clear all; close all; clc

% create your parameters
x = linspace(-50,50,51);
y = linspace(-100,100,52);
z = linspace(0,50,50);

% A function of three variables
fun = @(x,y,z) sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2);

% Preallocate
vaue = zeros(50,50,50);

% Populate the data matrix
for i = 1:numel(x)
    for j = 1:numel(y)
        for k = 1:numel(z)
            value(i,j,k) = fun(x(i),y(j),z(k));
        end
    end
end

% Generate a new surface or contour plot for each value of "z"
for k = 1:numel(z)
    figure(1)
    %contour(x,y,value(:,:,k)');
    surf(x,y,value(:,:,k)');
    title(sprintf('z = %f',z(k)));
    pause(0.1);
end
```